# Android Studio 3.1 stable version becomes inactive with text cursor,only way is to kill the process

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed android studio 3.1 stable version on my Ubuntu 16.04 version. After launch my project, whenever I click on code editor,it simply becomes text cursor and I am not able to do any click or edits. Complete Android studio becomes inactive,only way is I kill my java process on terminal.

I tried Known issue solutions for **Frozen keyboard input - "iBus" problems on Linux** (https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues.html),but nothing works for me.I dont know why stable version gets this kind of issues.How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am not having a problem like this on Ubuntu 17.10 with Android Studio 3.1, so this is not a general Android Studio-on-Ubuntu problem. There *are* points where it is very slow, though I usually see that on `build.gradle`. Do you encounter this problem with a newly-created project (instead of your existing one that you are trying)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I am facing on newly created project.Also it is not occurs only on build.gradle, it occurs on my kotlin classes also.